# how to set href tag to hold php variable and that variable contains a link to a different site?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql DB which directly stores links to different sites.
I fetch the link from DB and store it in a variable like this:

```
$tdl = $row["file"];
```

Now this $tdl has the link to a different site...
I use html tag to display it like this..:

```
<a href="<?php echo $tdl ;?>" target="_blank"><b><u>VIEW PDF DOCUMENT</b></u></a>
```

Now when i click on the link "VIEW PDF DOCUMENT" the new site is opened (eg http://www.IneedTOgoHERE.com). This works in local host but when I put my site online, It appends the link with my domain name, eg. http://www.myExampleDomain.com/www.IneedTOgoHERE.com.

I want to open just http://www.I need To go Here.com. How do I do that?

Comment: why dont just check the value by printing it ? it could be possible that in production server you have different value for row file

Comment: I suppose that problem is `$tdl` value not the way you're showing it

Comment: add the "http://" in your link

Comment: No $tdl works perfectly with localhost it redirects me to other site

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I already tried it..it prints the correct link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This,

```
<a href="<?php echo "http://".$tdl ;?>" target="_blank"><b><u>VIEW PDF DOCUMENT</u></b></a>
```

Comment: are you getting space between the links right?
so you have to replace that space , using $tdl = str_replace(' ', '', $tdl); and try again..

Comment: Actually whats happening is it appends the link like this... 
http:// w w w. m y do ma in . com/http://w w w . i need to go here . com/

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, your link is generating relative url links.

If `$row["file"]` doesn't include http in the database, you can hardcode that bit so it always shows. why not change your line to this?

```
<a href="http://<?php echo $tdl; ?>/" target="_blank">VIEW PDF DOCUMENT</a>
```

Comment: My DB contains link like this...it already contains http..
eg: h t t p s ://www.google.co.in/url

Comment: Okay, so if you echo `$tdl` what is the output you see?

Comment: output is:
 h t t p s : / / www.google.co.in/
(spaces added intentionally)

Comment: Then there's something wrong elsewhere, because even in simple HTML by putting a full URL in an `a` tag will not render it as a relative link.

Comment: Have you tried creating a hard coded link to an external URL, and seeing if that does the same thing?

Comment: afaik it should work fine and in your case it doesnt that means problem is anywhere else

Comment: Okay, so where's the problem then?

Comment: @Lee LOL with that much code in question its like reading mind of OP which i cant. Problem could be in htaccess or op didnt debugged code properly

Comment: Exactly my point, so the problem is somewhere else other than what we've been told...

Comment: @Chandreshsingh Why don't you try removing your files from your website including HTACCESS, and just uploading a simple php file, with your code above in it, but hardcode the value of $tdl to be a full url. Then upload it, and see what's being outputted for the link location.

Comment: I'll output the link in another page and then the user would click on that link to go to the desired website..

Answer (score 0):

```
if(substr($tdl, 0, 4) != "http") {
  $tdl = "http://".$tdl;
}
```

Comment: Are you putting this before its echos?

Comment: Sorry, autocomplete added the full word of string, try now.